# Is it possible to override the ABSPATH constant

Tags: wp-config

In 4.0 `wp-config-sample.php` contains

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

but `ABSPATH` is defined in `wp-load.php` before including `wp-config.php`

```
/** Define ABSPATH as this file's directory */
define( 'ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/' );

error_reporting( E_CORE_ERROR | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_USER_ERROR | E_USER_WARNING | E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR );

if ( file_exists( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php') ) {

    /** The config file resides in ABSPATH */
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-config.php' );
```

I assume `wp-config-sample.php` is out of sync with the actual code, but did I miss something and there is some other way to override `ABSPATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official reply is that `ABSPATH` is more for backward compatibility with code which was written when plugins were including `wp-config.php` and overriding `WP_CONTENT_DIR` should be enough.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29626#comment:3

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26592#comment:8